# How to get difference in days between two calendars in Datatimepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

How to get the difference between two datatimepickers : val and val2

```
 $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
          var val = $('#datetimepicker7').data('date'); 
      var val2 = $('#datetimepicker6').data('date'); 

         $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date);

            });
```

i tried

```
$("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
          var val = $('#datetimepicker7').data('date'); 
      var val2 = $('#datetimepicker6').data('date'); 
                var dateDifference = val - val2;

         $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date);
```

but the result of datedifference is NaN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [date difference in days in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075300/date-difference-in-days-in-javascript)

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina sorry but this method dont work for me

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you applied the answers to the proposed duplicate and how they didn't work for you. See [the help center article on duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have edit it

Comment: Then either `val` or `val2` is not a `Date` object.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the date is in format val2 = "09.12.2016 23:59:59

Comment: That's a `string`, not a `Date`.

Comment: ok thanks i will try to convert now

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just substract to dates ie:

```
var dateDifference = date1 - date2;
```

This will give you the difference in milliseconds. 
Then you will have to do some math to convert those milliseconds to the time unit you may need. Let's do days for example.

(24 hours in a day, 3600 seconds in an hour, and 1000ms in a second)

```
var daysDifference = parseInt(dateDifference/(24*3600*1000));
```

Hope this helps.